# Extract mail address from HTML-like string in Python

Tags: python, html-parsing, gmail-api

Using the GMail API it is possible to recover the sender of an email with:

```
email = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg['id']).execute()
payload = email['payload']
headers = payload['headers']
for hdr in headers:
if hdr['name'] == 'From':
   sender = hdr['value']
```

This returns the variable `sender` as a string with the format:

```
"Name Surname" <name.surname@gmail.com>
```

I would like to recover separately the name and email address from this string.
So that I end up with 2 (str) variables:

```
sender_name = "Name Surname"
sender_email_address = "name.surname@gmail.com"
```

Is there a library that can assist with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`email.utils` module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/library/email.utils.html#module-email.utils) has a [`parseaddr` function](https://docs.python.org/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parseaddr) that does exactly that:

> Parse address – which should be the value of some address-containing field such as *To* or *Cc* – into its constituent *realname* and *email address* parts. Returns a tuple of that information, unless the parse fails, in which case a 2-tuple of `('', '')` is returned.

An example:

```py
from email.utils import parseaddr

sender = '"Name Surname" <name.surname@gmail.com>'
sender_name, sender_email_address = parseaddr(sender)

sender_name
#=> 'Name Surname'

sender_email_address
#=> 'name.surname@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```
mys = '"Name Surname" <name.surname@gmail.com>'
name_email = mys.split("<")
sender_name = name_email[0].strip().strip('"')
sender_email_address = name_email[1].strip(">")
print(f"sender_name: {sender_name}")
print(f"sender_email_address: {sender_email_address}")
```

returns

```
Name Surname
name.surname@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation or regular expression;

```
import re
s='"Name Surname" <name.surname@gmail.com>'
re.search('^.*<', s).group()[:-1].strip()[1:-1]
'Name Surname'
re.search('<.*>',s).group()
'<name.surname@gmail.com>'
```